# EXCEL VBA Execute only if one or two columns updated

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there's a way to execute some VBA code only if data in one or two columns is updated. I know I can set it up to execute if any cell is updated and then check the target to see if it's in the correct columns, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Try some code first, then depending of your results or doubts post it here in order to help you, otherwise moderators will close your question.

Comment: The way you said you were going about it is how I would personally do it.

Comment: The intersect/target check seems to be the standard approach.